# The functions $f,g$ are non constant, differentiable, real valued functions..

Tags: real-analysis

[image]

I have found that $\cos{x}$ and $\sin{x}$ satisfies the given condition. But how to prove in general. Please give some hint

Comment: Yes, $f(x)=\cos\alpha x$ and $g(x)=\sin\alpha x$ satisfy (1) and (2), but so would some other functions. With $h(x)=f^2(x)+g^2(x)$, try to calculate $h(x+y)$ (and try to prove $h'(0)=0$).

Comment: @ProfessorVector I seem to show that $f(x)=\cos(\alpha x)$ and $g(x)=\pm\sin(\alpha x)$ in my answer, but maybe something's wrong there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Letting $x=y=0$ gives us straight away that $f(0)=1$.

Differentiating equation (1) we obtain
$$f'(x+y)=f'(x)f(y)-g'(x)g(y)$$
Set $x=0$, using $f'(0)=0$:
$$f'(y)=-g'(0)g(y)$$
for every $y$. Similarly differentiating equation (2) gives
$$g'(x+y)=f'(x)g(y)+g'(x)f(y)$$
and setting $x=0$ gives
$$g'(y)=g'(0)f(y)$$
for every $y$.

These equations show that $f$ and $g$ are twice differentiable, moreover
$$f''(y)=-g'(0)g'(y)=-g'(0)^2f(y)$$
by combining them. Let $\omega=g'(0)$. This is a simple differential equation whose general solution is
$$f(y)=A\cos(\omega y)+B\sin(\omega y)$$
Our initial conditions $f(0)=1$ and $f'(0)=0$ show us that
$$f(y)=\cos(\omega y)$$
Finally letting $x=y$ in equation (1) gives:
$$\cos(2\omega y)=\cos^2(\omega y)-g(y)^2$$
But since $\cos(2\omega y)=2\cos^2(\omega y)-1$ it follows
$$g(y)^2=1-\cos^2(\omega y)=1-f(y)^2$$
hence
$$f(y)^2+g(y)^2=1$$